# Android: can't get geolocation from network if phone is connected via WiFi

Tags: android, networking, geolocation

I'm trying to get geolocation from network like that:

```
boolean network_enabled = false;
LocationManager lm;
lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

try{
   network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
} catch(Exception ex){
   Log.v("my_log_tag", "network location exception: " + ex.toString());
}

if(network_enabled){
   lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
}
```

It works nice if my phone is connected only via cell network, but i have a problem: if my phone is connected not only via cell network, but to some WiFi access point too (say, my home access point), then i receive no location. It seems like Android tries to get geolocation using my WiFi access point, but of course it can't. How can i make Android get location from cell network and ignore any WiFi connection?

I definitely know it is possible, because, for example, [Yandex Maps application](http://goo.gl/Z3ydM) does it fine.

I need to say one more detail: this Yandex Maps application can receive geolocation via network even if i have NOT enabled checkbox *Settings* -> *Location and security* -> *Use wireless networks*. I have no idea how does it work, but maybe it uses completely different approach.

**The fact is**: if i have GPS enabled, it uses GPS. If i have GPS disabled, but cell network connection is enabled, then it uses network for geolocation, independently of WiFi connection and checkbox "*Use wireless networks*".

How can i do the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Out of the work I've done with retrieving a geolocation, wifi access points only will send their location periodically (30 seconds to 5 minutes). But, understand that `NETWORK_PROVIDER` recieves from cell towers as well (which is slow and inaccurate, but has better signal in buildings).

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
```

that is how I have found the fastest results for geolocation using the phone's gps, however using `NETWORK_PROVIDER` works, it is really slow and I have not been able to find a good solution to force the location to update faster.